# how to solve Unable to acquire application service error?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm try to study developing eclipse plug-in.
so, when i create and run the basic sample, this error is occurs.
In other solutions i searched, i can't use that.
please help me to solve this error.
I'm using eclipse LUNA version.

This is my config.ini

```html
#This configuration file was written by: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser
#Tue Nov 17 20:06:06 KST 2015
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.jee
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace
osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.1.v20140909-1633.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.1.0.v20131217-1203.jar@1\:start
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide
osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform
osgi.framework.extensions=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.1.v20140709-1414.jar,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.1.100.weaving-hook-20140821.jar,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.fx.osgi_2.1.0.201508240501.jar
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
```

This is error log.

```html
!SESSION Thu Jun 16 20:02:23 KST 2016 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2016-06-16 20:02:23.496
!MESSAGE Could not find extension: reference:file:D:/이클립스/EE
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2016-06-16 20:02:23.503
!MESSAGE Could not find extension: maven/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.1.v20140709-1414.jar
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2016-06-16 20:02:23.503
!MESSAGE Could not find extension: reference:file:D:/이클립스/EE
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2016-06-16 20:02:23.506
!MESSAGE Could not find extension: maven/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.1.100.weaving-hook-20140821.jar
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2016-06-16 20:02:23.506
!MESSAGE Could not find extension: reference:file:D:/이클립스/EE
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2016-06-16 20:02:23.508
!MESSAGE Could not find extension: maven/plugins/org.eclipse.fx.osgi_2.1.0.201508240501.jar
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2016-06-16 20:02:23.586
!MESSAGE Invalid splash path entry: maven/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0.v20140925-0400
!SESSION 2016-06-16 20:02:23.478 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.8.0_31
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=ko_KR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.platform.ide
Command-line arguments:  -product org.eclipse.platform.ide -data D:\Labworkspace/../runtime-EclipseApplication -dev file:D:/Labworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Eclipse Application/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-06-16 20:02:23.875
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:D:/이클립스/EE not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-06-16 20:02:23.876
!MESSAGE Bundle maven/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.1.v20140709-1414.jar not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-06-16 20:02:23.877
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:D:/이클립스/EE not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-06-16 20:02:23.877
!MESSAGE Bundle maven/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.1.100.weaving-hook-20140821.jar not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-06-16 20:02:23.877
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:D:/이클립스/EE not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-06-16 20:02:23.878
!MESSAGE Bundle maven/plugins/org.eclipse.fx.osgi_2.1.0.201508240501.jar not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-06-16 20:02:23.878
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:D:/이클립스/EE not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-06-16 20:02:23.879
!MESSAGE Bundle maven/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.1.0.v20131217-1203.jar@1:start not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-06-16 20:02:23.931
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:78)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i install eclipse neon and run it, it ran well.